# Syntax error while creating a google chrome extension

Tags: json, google-chrome

I keep getting a syntax error everytime I try to load the follow manifest.json:

```
{ 
"name":"Reada",
"version":"1.0",
"description":"An extension to enable functionality of Arc90's readability",
"background_page":"noway.html",
"browser_action":{ "default_icon":"hello.png" }
"permissions":"tabs"
}
```

Line 7, column 1, syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a comma after the `"browser_action"` entry. I find it handy to paste the JSON into a Python shell, which picks up syntax errors in a flash:

```
>>> { 
... "name":"Reada",
... "version":"1.0",
... "description":"An extension to enable functionality of Arc90's readability",
... "background_page":"noway.html",
... "browser_action":{ "default_icon":"hello.png" }
... "permissions":"tabs"
  File "<stdin>", line 7
    "permissions":"tabs"
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> }
```

Comment: What a silly mistake! Everytime I tried putting that comma out there, it said there was a trailing comma. And now it worked.